# How to determine 3d measurements

Tags: geometry, 3d, projective-geometry

I am trying to reproduce an artwork that is both a 2D drawing and 3D paper sculpture by Romanian artist Liviu Stoicoviu done in the 80s, The Triangle:

[image: The Triangle Paper Sculpture by Liviu Stoicoviciu]

[image: The Triangle 2D Drawing by Liviu Stoicoviciu]

I have tried to trace the 2D artwork which is helpful for understanding the structure, but also confusing at the same time, as it's easy to get lost in recursion and the ambiguity between the 2d and 3d representation of the shapes:

[image: triangle 2d redraw]

Is it possible to determine 3d properties of the shape from the 2d projection such as:

- dimensions (side length, thickness) and angles ?
- projection/perspective parameters ?

The good part is the shape is has radial symmetry.

I believe the 3d artwork is derived from the 2d one using descriptive geometry, which I'm only now starting to look at. I also must mention I barely understand a few basic mathematical concepts so please be patient and try to explain in 'mere mortal' terms.